# KeyError: 'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'

Tags: python, pytorch

today I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67724544/runtimeerror-cuda-error-invalid-device-ordinal) concerning problems with PyTorch running on my GPU. In response, someone kindly suggested running the following code:

```
import os
num_gpus = os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'].split(',').__len__()
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = ','.join(f'{i}' for i in range(num_gpus))
```

However, after running that second line, unfortunately I get another error:

```
num_gpus = os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'].split(',').__len__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/hbp/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'
```

I tried to look it up, but couldn't find anything helpful.

Does anyone have an idea what I could try? The question I linked to may have relevant info.

Comment: Clearly CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES is not set and isn't causing a problem

Comment: By default `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` does not exist. It only after you set it that it is usable.

Comment: There's no point doing fancy things when your machine has only one GPU. Just use `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = "0"`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! FYI, that didn't work, but I have adjusted so I no longer need this.